# How to cast KeyPath<CNContact, Array<CNLabeledValue>> to KeyPath<CNContact, Any>

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, swift-keypath

I need to put KeyPath values in an array of type Array<KeyPath<CNContact,Any>>. However, \CNContact.phoneNumbers fails to cast to KeyPath<CNContact,Any>.

Here is my test code:

```
let keyPath0: KeyPath<CNContact,Any> = \CNContact.phoneNumbers // Runtime error message: Key path value type '[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Any'

let keyPath: KeyPath<CNContact,Any> = \CNContact.phoneNumbers as! KeyPath<CNContact,Any> // Warning message: Cast from 'KeyPath<CNContact, [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]>' to unrelated type 'KeyPath<CNContact, Any>' always fails
```

Comment: The `Value` of `KeyPath` is a generic representing **one** concrete type. It cannot be `Any`.

Comment: I can be `Any`. But then it's `Any`. `[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]` is a different type than `Any`. What's being requested here is impossible. KeyPaths are required to know their type. (If that type is Any, that's ok, but that means literally Any, not "I don't care what type it is.)

Comment: @RobNapier So how would I include KeyPath<CNContact,String> and KeyPath<CNContact,Array<CNLabeledValue>> in the same array?

Comment: `[PartialKeyPath<CNContact>]`